# Which mathematician (or theoretician), while ill, applied great mental efforts, saying only intense concentration enabled him to tolerate the pain?

Tags: math-history

Title nearly explains it. I couldn't remember the exact figure in the anecdote. He suffered from a certain illness or such for a time, and said that intense mental effort was the only thing that made the pain tolerable.

Comment: Pascal?   A toothache?   His mystic hexagon.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Never ask your question inthe title.

Comment: What about Euler?

Comment: @GauravChandan thanks